# How to get return code in sbt of another internal command (not external command)?

Tags: scala, sbt

My `build.sbt` file is like the following:

```
import sys.process._
def makeProject = Command.args("make", "<args>") {
    (state, args) => {
        val exec = Exec("run", None);
        val makeCommand = ("make " + args.mkString(" "));
        val newState = MainLoop.processCommand(exec, state);
        // run is an internal command of sbt which can be executed from sbt terminal
        // what I need is the return code of the `run` INTERNAL command
        // if(exec's execution failed) do not execute the following makeCommand
        makeCommand!;
        newState;
    }
}
```

I need to get the return code of `Exec("run", None)`. If it ran successfully, the makeCommand after it should be executed - otherwise, do not execute the makeCommand.

Comment: What is the return type of Exec / what does `exec` return? You could do a pattern match on `exec`

Comment: @JamesWhiteley , the type of Exec : https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/Exec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a **task** which depends on an internal task, like this:

```
myTask := {
  val x = run.value
  val args = Seq("my", "args")
  val makeCommand = ("make " + args.mkString(" "))
  makeCommand!
}
```

Now how to make the args more easily settable? I would suggest the most sbt idiomatic way would be to define them as **settings** in the build.sbt, and depend on them in your task.